# Resize Output Layer in Keras Python

Tags: python, keras, resize, reshape

my goal is to resize the output image from **[32,32,1]** to **[8,8,1]**

I try this with reshape but became a error:

```
Output_model = Reshape((8,8,-1))(out_1)
Error when checking target: expected reshape_1 to have shape (8, 8, 32) but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)
```

How can I solve this problem??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you cannot reshape the array directly because 32*32*1 not equal to 8*8*1, therefore you have to subsample:

```
import keras
x=keras.layers.Input((32,32,1))
x=keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((4,4))(x)
```

then your image will downsample to (8,8,1).

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Its works. But now I have the following Error: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_5 to have shape (8, 8, 1) but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)

Comment: can you please write a small code reproducing the error?

Comment: This is very dificult to write a small code because my code is very complex. I can try explain the Error: I set my Image Dataset as Keras.generator and compile my model. This works. I see the Input(32x32), Layers and my output(8x8).. Then I wait 30-40sec my IDE plot the Error during the fit-function: ValueError: Error when checking target: expected max_pooling2d_5 to have shape (8, 8, 1) but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)

Comment: can you at least write the code of the network graph?

Comment: I add my architecutre in the description